# Can services in Angular be decouple like microservices?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my example code I have two services: `FooService` and `BarService`.

`BarService` is calling `foo()` function from `FooService`.

`AppComponent` is inject the `BarService` and calling to `bar()` function from `BarService`.

Right now, BarService is depend on `FooService`.

I wounding if there is a way to make `BarService` not be depend on `FooService`? so they not talk with each other and will not know about each other?

I saw in microservice approach that services can talk with each other without direct connection by using http-request.

This is apply to this use case?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-aphlkt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbar%2Fbar.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Ffoo%2Ffoo.service.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class BarService {
  constructor(private fooService: FooService) {}

  bar() {
    console.log('in bar');

    this.fooService.foo();
  }
}
```

Comment: What you mean about  make `BarService` not be depend on `FooService`

Comment: You could use custom events to orchestrate your code if you need a business-event-like dependency rather than a direct dependency.

Comment: I mean right now `BarService` is calling to `FooService` directly. I want to call `FooService` foo function without directly like microservice communicate with each other

Comment: You're calling  `fooService.foo()` in `BarService`, so naturally it has to know about it. As an alternative you could have `FooService` emit an event that is held in a separate service and subscribe to that event instead.

Comment: I think that this is up to how dependency injection works in Angular. Both services are Singleton (providedInRoot) so if you want to use some functionality of one of them inside the other you have to inject it, so Angular can tell wich one build first, and dont got 'undefined' trying to use it

Comment: While you can invent your own event bus (or just use Javascript events in some way), it’s questionable how much sense it makes to detach Angular services. Distributed micro services are typically good for scaling and performance, along with easing maintenance by separating code bases. Which of these points will apply to a Javascript app? Probably none. It’s still going to run within the browser, and you probably won’t separate the services into their own code repositories. So what’s the advantage exactly?

Comment: `Decoupling the Service` - What exactly is the problem... `Type` of the service or `Instance` of the service... because switching the mechanism will come along with it's own set of overheads. For example, if using the `event` mechanism of the browser, synchnronization between `BarService` and `FooService` will come along as an additional overhead ... It would be better if you can share with us what exactly is the problem which is causing you to go en-route this decoupling solution?

Comment: However, if it's only the `Type of the Service` we could use other means of `InjectionToken` provided by Angular.